# Manually installing SVN plugin in Eclipse Helios on RedHat

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

The exact OS I'm using is **RedHat 6.5 Enterprise**, 32 bit. I believe Eclipse was installed using **yum**.

I have tried multiple URLs to try to install an SVN plugin using Eclipse's **Help->Install New Software** function, including this one: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x, which I found here: http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Eclipse installed the plugin successfully, but whenever I start Eclipse, the plugin is nowhere to be found. I tried starting Eclipse with the **-clean** option, and that isn't doing anything.

Therefore, from the site I linked above, I downloaded the .zip file of the plugin from here: http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240. The exact file I downloaded is **site-1.8.22.zip**.

I had this same problem in the past with Mercurial where installing from Help->Install New Software didn't work, so I downloaded that jar (for some reason there is only one jar for Mercurial but for SVN there are many plus some directories?). I then put that jar in **/usr/share/eclipse/dropins/plugins** (I had to create the plugins directory). That worked. However, when I put all of the SVN jars in there, SVN is not showing up in Eclipse. I have tried many different combinations of putting only some jars in there, creating folders, etc. Again, I have been using -clean when starting eclipse, and that's not making a difference. I truly think the plugin isn't being put in the right spot because I can move the Mercurial plugin I have installed in and out, and it shows that correctly in Eclipse each time. For reference, the Mercurial jar I'm using is: **com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_2.1.0.201304290948.jar**

I also noticed that **/etc/eclipse.ini** has this line in it, which should say where to look for plugins: **-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins**

So I have some questions:

1. Where do I put all of these SVN jars and folders that I downloaded?
2. Why does the Mercurial one only have one jar and the SVN have a whole bunch? I'm just curious why the developers would package these completely differently because maybe this means there's a single SVN jar out there that I could use and just have it work.
3. I also found a **/usr/lib/eclipse** folder, and there are also plugin and dropin folders in there. Why are there multiple Eclipse directories for plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was using the wrong version of java. I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, and that required me to update my java version in order to run it. I updated to **1.8** (was using **1.6**). I think the latest Subclipse plugin requires something at least higher than 1.6. There were no warnings or error messages to let me know about this, so that's why it was difficult to figure out.

Once I started using the new Eclipse and Java 1.8, I was able to easily install and use Subsclipse using **Help->Install New Software**.